# Mocking class object having setter getter methods present in function using mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito, powermockito

I have a requirement in which I need to get some response from webservice. Need to mock function getPdf. I am unable to mock `GetDocumentRequest` and `GetDocumentResponse`.
Mockito or PowerMockito I need to use for mocking.
Eg:

```
Class xyz {
    // mocking required.
    String getPdf (int I, String h){
        return  getDoc(I, h):
     }

    String getDoc (int I, String h){
        GetDocumentRequest d = factory.getDocument ():
        d.setversion (I);
        d.setname (h):
        GetDocumentResponse r  = getService ().getPdfDoc (d):
        // webservice
        return r.getPdfString ();
   }


}
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. If you need to mock `getPdfDoc()`; well then obviously you have to actually mock the object that your call to `getService()` would return. And your code doesn't tell us what `getService()` is actually doing. Side note: avoid all mocking frameworks that carry "power" in their name. They cause more trouble than good.

Comment: use spock. This will be less intrusive to your code and keep your tests cleaner.

Comment: I need to mock getPdf () which in turn calls getDoc (). Iam not able to mock getdocumentRequest and GetDocumentResponse object

Answer (score 1):

Mockito should be enough for mocking a normal method. 
Maybe something similar to this?

```
@Test
public void test() {
   Xyz xyz = mock(Xyz.class);
   when(xyz.getPdf(any(Integer.class), any(String.class)).thenReturn("this is my pdf");
}
```

Comment: But GetDocumentRequest and GetDocumentResponse doesnt get mocked in this thus returning null

Comment: ok. I then don't quite understand the question I have to admit.